# Colouring a bar in your HTML popup

Tags: javascript, html

hello how do i color a bar that i have created in my element based on my function when i try to reference the element ID it returns null because it hasn't been created yet if i add the edit to the html creation it works but i want to make a function that will create the bar and the color it becomes this is what i have so far
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

```
const displayPopup = (pokelist) => {
const type = pokelist.types.map( type => type.type.name).join(", ");
// console.log(type)
const htmlpopUP = `
<div class="popup">
    <button id="closeButton" onclick="closePopup()"> X </button>
        <div class="pictures">
            <img class="pokeImagePop" src="${pokelist.sprites.front_default}"/>
            <h1> ${pokelist.id}. ${pokelist.name.toUpperCase()}</h1>
            <p>Type: ${type}</p>
            <p>Stats</p>
            <div id="stats">
            <p class="hp">${pokelist.stats[0].stat.name.toUpperCase()}: ${pokelist.stats[0].base_stat} <p id="barID" style="width:${pokelist.stats[0].base_stat*2}px; height: 10px";> </p> </p>
            <p class="attack">${pokelist.stats[1].stat.name.toUpperCase()}: ${pokelist.stats[1].base_stat}</p>
            <p class="defence">${pokelist.stats[2].stat.name.toUpperCase()}: ${pokelist.stats[2].base_stat}</p>
            <p class="SpAttack">${pokelist.stats[3].stat.name.toUpperCase()}: ${pokelist.stats[3].base_stat}</p>
            <p class="SpDefence">${pokelist.stats[4].stat.name.toUpperCase()}: ${pokelist.stats[4].base_stat}</p>
            <p class="speed">${pokelist.stats[5].stat.name.toUpperCase()}: ${pokelist.stats[5].base_stat}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>`;
// console.log(bar)
pokedex.innerHTML = htmlpopUP + pokedex.innerHTML;
}


 const createBarColor = () => {
 if (bar.width() <= 80){
 bar.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 console.log(bar)
 }
 else{
     bar.style.backgroundColor = "green"
 }
}
```

Comment: Paste the code, not images, pls

Comment: Pls, add the complete code and not the images of code.

Comment: In if condition width is attribute not a function

Comment: i tried using it as an attribute it still didn't work

Comment: Can you please add a reproducible fiddle link or code snippet, otherwise the code block you gave is not very much understandable regarding your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    bar = document.getElementsByClassName("bar");
    for (i = 0; i <= bar.length; i++){
    barWidth = [parseInt(bar[`${i}`].style.width)]
    createBarColor()



function createBarColor() {
if (barWidth <= 80){
    bar[`${i}`].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
else if (barWidth <= 160){
    bar[`${i}`].style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
}
else{
    bar[`${i}`].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(7, 205, 7)"
}
}
```

this is what i made to complete it sorry i have been working not replying to the comments sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to pass the stat value.

```js
function StatCell(base) {
  const percent = base > 180 ? 100 : base * (100 / 180);
  const color =
    base < 30
      ? "#f34444"
      : base >= 30 && base < 60
      ? "#ff7f0f"
      : base >= 60 && base < 90
      ? "#ffdd57"
      : base >= 90 && base < 120
      ? "#a0e515"
      : base >= 120 && base < 150
      ? "#23cd5e"
      : "#00c2b8";
      const bar = document.createElement('div');
      bar.style.width = percent+'%';
      bar.style.backgroundColor = color;
      bar.style.height = '15px';
  return bar;
}

document.getElementById('stat').appendChild(StatCell(50));
```

```html
<body>
<div id="stat"><b>HP</b></div>
</body>
```